# Build Customization in VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have the following problem with my software in Visual C++. 
I've set some Build Customization related to the file in the path: $(VCTargetsPAth)\BuildCustomizations\PROGNAME 4.2.targets
On a different pc I have a different version of the same file (for ex: PROGNAME 5.0.targets); when I open my VC++ project, I have to edit the *.vcxproj file in order to set manually the new version of targets.
Is there a method to avoid this problem and make the project available with different versions of targets file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it by referencing a short cut instead.   Each machine has a short cut in a known location that refers to what ever you need to refer to.